# Parse /proc/mounts and substitude only one field

Tags: bash, awk, substitution

I am looking for a way to print informations from /proc/mounts like that:

```
/home     /dev/md9    /dev/mapper/home    home
/var/tmp  /dev/md7    /dev/mapper/vartmp  vartmp
```

I try:

```
awk '{ print $2 " " $1; gsub("/","",$2); print "/dev/mapper/"$2" "$2 }' /proc/mounts
```

But the result is on two lines:

```
/home /dev/mapper/home
/dev/mapper/home home
/var/tmp /dev/md7
/dev/mapper/vartmp vartmp
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I have missed the 'hello" in my copy paste, and impossible to add it when editing my question, so : hello there ;)

Comment: If you would have included a greeting, somebody would probably have edited your question to remove it. We prefer the text in questions to be strictly on-topic. But thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fix**

> - use printf ( to avoid the implicit linefeed )
> - add whitespace to separate the printf from the gsub output

**adjusted command**

```
awk '{ printf $2 " " $1 " "; gsub("/","",$2); print "/dev/mapper/"$2" "$2 }' /proc/mounts
```

**input.txt**

```
/dev/mapper/home /home blah blah blah blah
```

**output**

```
$ awk '{ printf $2 " " $1 " "; gsub("/","",$2); print "/dev/mapper/"$2" "$2 }' input.txt 
/home /dev/mapper/home /dev/mapper/home home
```